# Files under src/main/resources goes under target/WEB-INF/classes

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

The project is a Spring MVC with Maven.

Here is the sample folder structure :

- src/main/java
- src/main/resources

  - css
  - fonts
  - images
  - js
  - messages_en.properties
- src/main/webapp

  - WEB-INF

    - views
    - application-context.xml
    - web.xml

And here is the build part of effective pom

```
<sourceDirectory>${basedir}\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
<scriptSourceDirectory>${basedir}\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
<outputDirectory>${basedir}\target\classes</outputDirectory>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>${basedir}\src\main\resources</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
<directory>${basedir}\target</directory>
<finalName>m2mproject</finalName>
```

And the target directory comes out like this

- WEB-INF

  - classes

    - com....
    - images
    - fonts
    - js
    - css
    - messages_en.properties
  - lib
  - views
  - apllication-context.xml
  - web.xml

Why maven puts all resources  under the classes folder? Is my folder structure wrong ?

Comment: This is exactly correct. Are you having a problem?

Comment: should images,fonts and js folders be under the classes folder ?

Comment: The _resources_ are _classpath_ resources. Everything gets put into `WEB-INF/classes`. These are different to _remote_ resources - which should live in `webapp` **outside of** `WEB-INF`. Maven is doing exactly what it should.

Comment: No, they should be on src/main/webapp/ or a subfolder of this path.

Comment: Hmmm.. Thank you both. I'm new to Java, it just seemed wrong, so I thought i should ask. So the files under src/main/resources are for spring to use as resource files ? Like, if I decide to call a resource property with @Value annotation, that resources file should be in that directory, am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

Let explain, briefly, maven behaviour

The stuff put in src/main/resources is supposed to be reachable from classpath. So in case of web application it will be put in WEB-INF/classes

The stuff put in src/main/webapp will be copied, as is, to in web application root

Answer (score 1):

Maven is doing right but
since you are using spring MVC youre resources are supposed to be a static resource and should be put under

main/webapp/resources

while your pages will be under

main/webapp/WEB-INF/views

and should contains .html or .jsp pages

now for main/resources are intended for configuation files such as persistence.xml or faces properties and any other that will be used for "java" classes.